# How to select all the down-down in an excel from a cell using python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, openpyxl

I need some help with Python code.
I am trying to select all the drop-down values from a cell Excel using Python code.

Below code I am using. It's not giving me the correct output.

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook

def get_dropdown_values(file_path, cell):
    workbook = load_workbook(file_path)
    sheet = workbook['TOR']
    
    for data_validation in sheet.data_validations.dataValidation:
        if cell in data_validation.sqref:
            if data_validation.type == 'list':
                return data_validation.formula1.split(',')
    return None

file_path = "305.xlsx"
cell_with_dropdown = "B46"  
dropdown_values = get_dropdown_values(file_path, cell_with_dropdown)
if dropdown_values:
    print("Dropdown values:", dropdown_values)
else:
    print("No dropdown menu found in the specified cell.")
```

**Output**: Dropdown values: ['$AX$7:$AX$38']

I need the drop-down values from the cell.
Drop-down values of the cell[B46] are TOR, XYM,WPQ, AAA

Thank You

Comment: Sample.xlsx couldn't be visited

Comment: Hi @linpingta, its just the name of the file.

Comment: It's not clear [What you are asking]. Create, please, a [example].

Comment: Hi @Vitalizzare, thank you. I have updated my question for more clarification.

Comment: Looks like the answer is correct. Check what's inside of the `AX7:AX38` cells.

Comment: You should really look at the data validation object in detail. If the code is correct, it's returning a range of cells with values to be checked against.

Comment: Your code will return the Data Validation 'Settings' Source box value. That can either be the actual values ' TOR, XYM,WPQ, AAA' if you have physically entered the values into that field or it will give you the range where the source data is held. You are getting the later, `$AX$7:$AX$38` is where the list values are on the sheet so read the values in that range and you have your list values.